# Implementing Nested UITabeViewControllers

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the attached screen view which shows the user profile as a header and many other widgets which can be shown as per user preferences.
[image]
I am not sure what is the best way to implement such UI.

My first assumption is to build UITabeViewController and have the widgets as UITableViewCell(s), but as you can notice that each widget is representing a stand-alone UITabeViewController. In the end, I will have many UITabeViewControllers nested on one main UITabeViewController.

I have to manage all these UITabeViewControllers delegates and data sources.

I am wondering whether there is a better approach to implement this UI, or I have to stick with my assumption?

Many thanks

Comment: How about making each widget a _section_ of the table view?

Comment: I think your original idea is correct, these widgets are each sections composed with custom cells inside a single UITableViewController, possibly custom SectionHeaderViews as well. The grouped style would probably suit the design mock the best (without TableSectionHeader titles). In your `cellForRow` function, that is part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, you can load different cells for each indexPath. These cells you can for example define as custom Nibs, to reflect the design you want. Or as prototype cells in the ViewController's Storyboard. Same goes for SectionHeaderViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

1. Consider every widget as a section in the tableview.
2. Use UICollectionView to show the data for each section (this will be helpful as some of the sections show data in form of a list, so basically each UICollectionView will scroll vertically), each collection view will have one section and the titles such as Approvals, UpComings, etc can become section headers.
3. Make a dummy TableViewCell whose functionality will be only to add a view as its subview, give it some corner radius, shadow, and any other ui changes required.
4. For each section dequeue a reusable cell with different names (can be the names of sections, this will enable the cells to be reused and not rendered on every scroll)
5. Lastly add the corresponding the collection views as subviews to the cell created in step 3.

This will help you make the code flexible. So later if you need to add horizontal scrollable sections/widgets it will be the same flow, thus having a consistent code.

Answer (score 1):

There can be one approach like below -

1. Don't create a table for the list of widgets. You can add custom views on a scroll view.
2. You can make a profile widget as a normal UIView.
3. For approvals, upcoming, delegations, my requests widgets embed a table view. The reason is that there can be repetitive patterns in these widgets as per your UI.
4. Set the height of table view fixed by calculating height using the number of rows and its height(from the code).

I've not tried it on XCode. But it can reduce the complexity of having a tableview inside tableview.